# Using Where in Select statement while Union in Mysql

Tags: mysql, sql

i am facing problems while specifying where condition in select statement for uninon of my three tables. Here is my code

```
create table master_data(
select id,number,product_id
from tablename_A
where id REGEXP '^[0-9]*$' and id != ' ' and product_id != 0 and product_id is not null
union
select id,number,product_id
from tablename_B
where id REGEXP '^[0-9]*$' and id != ' ' and product_id != 0 and product_id is not null
union
select id,number,product_id
from tablename_C
where id REGEXP '^[0-9]*$' and id != ' ' and product_id != 0 and product_id is not null
);
```

i am getting this error:

> You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that
>   corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use
>   near 'id != ' ' and product_id != 0 and product_id is not
>   nullunionselect id' at line 8

Comment: @Drew it's not a dupe sir.
the least you could do is help me if you know the answer. Thankyou.

Comment: What, the dupe looks pretty unrelated as the OP asks for the error in the select statement

Comment: @SRingne " product_id is not nullunionselect v" You are missing whitespaces in your query. Check the error message. Though I can't find that line in your code. Are you showing the correct snippet?

Comment: reopened my bad. Will be back in a few to see where you are at with it

Comment: @Philipp i editer the question, please take a look  at the error part "product_id is not nullunionselect id"

Comment: Have you formatted the sql yourself or is this how it is send to the database? Normally mysql can handle the linebreak and would not throw an error. If you are programmaticaly building this query you are forgetting a whitespace to concatenate the parts I guess

Answer (score 1):

first of all, what is 'REGEXP' ?

I prefer this:

```
WITH master_data AS 
(
   select
      id,
      number,
      product_id 
   from
      tablename_A 
   union
   select
      id,
      number,
      product_id 
   from
      tablename_B 
   union
   select
      id,
      number,
      product_id 
   from
      tablename_C 
)
SELECT
   * 
FROM
   master_data 
WHERE
   id NOT IN '^[0-9]*$' 
   and id != ' ' 
   and product_id != 0 
   and product_id is not null
```

Comment: REGEXP' is used for removing alphanumeric values in id column and selecting only numbers.
my id column is of categogy varchar(100)

Answer (score 0):

The following works fine on mysql 5.6.31 (Microsoft Server) and mysql 5.7.14 (Redhat Linux)

```
create table tablename_A
(   id int not null,
    product_id int not null,
    number int not null
);
create table tablename_B
(   id int not null,
    product_id int not null,
    number int not null
);
create table tablename_C
(   id int not null,
    product_id int not null,
    number int not null
);


create table master_data as
select id,number,product_id
from tablename_A
where (id REGEXP '^[0-9]*$') and id != ' ' and product_id != 0 and product_id is not null
union
select id,number,product_id
from tablename_B
where (id REGEXP '^[0-9]*$') and id != ' ' and product_id != 0 and product_id is not null
union
select id,number,product_id
from tablename_C
where id REGEXP '^[0-9]*$' and id != ' ' and product_id != 0 and product_id is not null;
```